# Data Movement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, bulkinsert

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have two tables `Table_A` & `Table_B`.

`Table_A` has 20 million records & `Table_B` is empty with same structure of `Table_A`. I want to move the records from `Table_A` to `Table_B` with condition (90 days previous records,  15 million records) without any performance issue. What would be the best solution to move the data?

Data has to be deleted from `Table_A` once it got moved to `Table_B`.

Comment: Not a stack overflow question i believe

Comment: What do you mean by "crore"?

Comment: You should stick to **internationally accepted** units of measure - thousands, millions, billions - "crore" and "lakh" and others are **NOT** universally known and many people will not know what amount of data you're referring to....

Comment: 2 crore = 20 Million records

Comment: And even when several people commented to you about using Indian words, you still didn't do anything to fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think in plain SQL:

```
INSERT INTO target
    SELECT as_is_col1, as_is_col2,
    FROM source
    WHERE wanted_col BETWEEN 0 AND 200000000;
```

Comment: Maybe you should equip your `insert` command with a column list. This will make things much clearer, especially when there is an `identity` (primary key) column involved. In that case you will also have to place a `set identity_insert target_tbl on;` command before it. Only then you will get the *same* id numbers in both tables.

Comment: Bro.. It will leads to table lock for long time. Since it is very important business table, im thinking to do it like in the plain sql query